# YouTubeData api v3 を用いたYouTuve Liveのチャット（コメント）取得について

Tags: youtube-data-api

[YouTube ヘルプ フォーラムにて同様の質問](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-ja/_XSVqnxZz4Y;context-place=forum/youtube-ja)をさせていただいたところ，
こちらに誘導いただいたため，質問失礼します．

**【目的】**
YouTube Liveのチャットの情報を取得したい．

**【現状】**
YouTubeの動画のコメントを取得するapiとして，CommentThreadsのlistメソッドがあり，動画のidを指定することでその動画のコメントを取得することは確認できました．

YouTube Liveの場合，YouTubeの動画と同様にurlに[ v=○○○○ ] と動画id？があるため，そのidを指定してapiを試したところ，コメントが取得できず，取得できたとしても過去のコメント（生放送中のチャットの内容ではない）でした．
YouTube Liveのコメントについて調べたところ，生放送中のコメント（チャット）は生放送が終了した後にコメントとしてプレーヤの下に表示されるらしく，チャットとコメントの扱いが違うこと，上記のapiでは後者のコメントが取得できることがわかりました．
(参考: YouTubeヘルプ | ライブチャット　https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=ja)

**【質問】**
私は生放送中にチャット内容を取得したいのですが，なにか方法はないでしょうか？
※取得したい情報は私自身が配信する生放送のものではなく，第三者が配信する生放送のチャットです．

長くなってしまいましたが，よろしくお願い致します．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

誘導された先はおそらく日本語版SOではなく英語版本家SOの方だと思いますが……

それはさておき英語版の方でちょっと検索してみると、まさに同じような質問がなされているようです。

- [How to obtain a feed of comments entered through the 'chat' box during a YouTube live broadcast? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229728/how-to-obtain-a-feed-of-comments-entered-through-the-chat-box-during-a-youtube)
- [How to get chat content of Youtube live event in Java - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418455/how-to-get-chat-content-of-youtube-live-event-in-java)

これの後者の方に約1年前の日付で [google の開発者の方](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya) からの回答が載っています。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427743/5120044

> The API doesn't have connection to live chat at this moment. We are hoping to get that content incorporated into API soon.

要するにまだそのようなAPIはないという話なのですが、この回答に付いた今年8月31日の同じ方のコメントとして、

> We have an API for it in testing stage for now. We hope to have it open eventually.

とすでにテスト段階に入っているとあるので、そう遠くないうちにAPIが公開されるのではないかと思われます。